# Searching points inside certain radius

Tags: django, postgis, geodjango

I've got the following Point model:

```
class Point(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=50)
    location = PointField()
```

I'm now trying to get all the point in a distance of 5 km of that Point:

```
points = Point.objects.filter(location__dwithin=(point.location, D(km=5)))
```

But then I get the following error:
*FieldError: Join on field 'location' not permitted. Did you misspell 'dwithin' for the lookup type?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem - RTFM. Every model needs the following field:

```
 objects = models.GeoManager()
```

Comment: In Django 2 the `GeoManager` and `GeoQuerySet` classes are removed (in favour of nothing, they aren't required anymore AFAIK). Ref. [2.0 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/#features-removed-in-2-0)